# React Component Rendering but not visible in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

As the title says, none of my react components are visible when I run rails server. I am using the gem `react-rails`. I know they're rendering because when inspecting the body tag of the page, it has `<div data-react-class="Home" data-react-props="{}"></div>`.

To test if it was my computer, I made another rails application, created a react component in my root with the exact same format, being

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

and it showed up on screen. I have absolutely no errors in my console, so I have no idea what the problem is. The difference between the two rails apps(the visible and non visible) are that the broken one is using devise, bootstrap, and has more migrations/models/controllers. Also, I removed turbolinks in the broken one, but even adding it back in, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Why do you have spaces after the carrots?

Comment: because it doesn't show up on stackoverflow otherwise, theres no spaces in my actual app

Comment: you just need to format your text into code, and it will display properly, also @MatthewHerbst "caret"

Comment: @azium stupid auto-correct! @Nico: to format on SO correctly you can highlight all your code and click the `{}` button in the text editor, or, just make sure the entire code block is indented 4 spaces. If you want to set the language you can do that by referencing http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I would check if react_ujs is required in the js bundle.
After that I would inspect the bundle that the js got transpiled corrently.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Using `react-rails` gem.

No console error, webpacker compiled successfully. Also helper was working good `react_component('Home')` cause I could see in the html

```html
<div data-react-class="Home" data-react-props="{}"></div>
```

When installing the gem the following example was within:

```js
// Run this example by adding <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %> 
// to the head of your layout file,
// like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. 

// All it does is render <div>Hello React</div> at the bottom
// of the page.

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Hello = props => (
  <div>Hello {props.name}!</div>
)

Hello.defaultProps = {
  name: 'David'
}

Hello.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="React" />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

Which was working good.

But the component is rendered when `DOMContentLoaded` event triggers. So the component was rendered by the client.

Anyways, reading the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#view-helper) found `prerender`

> prerender: true to render the component on the server.

So using `=react_component("Home", {}, {prerender: true})` worked to me.